# What is the difference between "Bisphosphate" and "Diphosphate" in biochemistry?

Tags: biochemistry, terminology

I have often found bisphosphate compounds ( e.g. RuBP, RuBisCO, 2,3-BPGA etc.) and diphosphate compounds (e.g. ADP, GDP etc.) in biochemistry. They are commonly seen and are important compounds in both animals and plants but what is the basic difference between a bisphosphate and a diphosphate?

Comment: For example fructose 1,6 bisphosphate is used in step four of glycolysis but d location of the phosphate group has been mentioned already ,1 telling us carbon 1 and 6 telling us carbon 6(no offence) but i think its the same thing as bisphosphate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image]

<sup>[[Source:Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_diphosphate)]</sup>

As you can see in the above structure of ADP(Adenosine **di**-phosphate), the two phosphate groups in the compound are directly attached to one another. So it is named as **di**-phosphate. [[Source](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/misc/phospho.html#r3)] You can see [this](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/misc/phos2t8.html#t2) table for more examples.

[image]

<sup>[[Source:Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate)]</sup>

In this structure of RuBP(Ribulose-1,5-**bis**phosphate), the two phosphate groups in the compound are not directly attached to one another, they are attached to first and fifth carbon, meaning they are attached to different atoms. Therefore, it is named as **bis**-phosphate. [[Source](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/misc/phospho.html#r3)](2<sup>nd</sup> comment)

Comment: I believe this is the correct distinction, but historically the two terms have been used interchangeably. As an example, a lot of biologists will still refer to 2,3-BPG as 2,3-DPG.